# Why is Turbolinks not working properly? Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

wondering why turbolinks isn't working properly...driving me nuts. When I refresh the page everything works fine. However, navigating to a page for the first time, the javascript doesn't load properly. See slick.js below for reference.

1. When navigating to any page for the first time.

   - alert pops up before page actually renders
   - javascript features fail
2. When navigating back to page that I have already been too in the current    session. The contents of body clearly loads before the alert pops up, and the       javascript features work as expected.

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more information, I believe I included the important files below. Thanks!

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'

# gem 'sassc-rails'


# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# HTML5/CSS Framework
gem 'bourbon', '4.2.6'
gem 'neat', '1.7.4'
gem 'bitters', '1.2.0'
gem 'refills', '0.1.0'



gem 'normalize-rails', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "rspec-rails"
    gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require refills/centered_navigation
//= require slick
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MySite</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Candal' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
    <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css"/>


</head>
<body>
    <!-- <div class="appWrap"> -->

    <%= render 'refills/centered_navigation' %>
    <div class="wrapper-for-content-outside-of-footer">
        <!-- Uncomment this whole section for a sticky footer. The content of the page should be inside of this .wrapper-for-content-outside-of-footer -->
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render '/refills/footer_2' %>


    <!-- </div> -->

</body>
</html>
```

_ecommerce.html.erb

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <!-- Add nice arrow images for the slider -->
    <div class="prev">  <   </div>
    <div class="next">  >   </div>

    <div class="product-slider">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x750">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x750">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x750">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row column text-center">
    <h2>Our Newest Products</h2>
    <hr>
</div>

<div class="row small-up-2 large-up-4">
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button expanded">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button expanded">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button expanded">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button expanded">Buy</a>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row column">
    <div class="callout primary">
        <h3>Really big special this week on items.</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="row column text-center">
    <h2>Some Other Neat Products</h2>
    <hr>
</div>

<div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-6">
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button small expanded hollow">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button small expanded hollow">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button small expanded hollow">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button small expanded hollow">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button small expanded hollow">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <h5>Nulla At Nulla Justo, Eget</h5>
        <p>$400</p>
        <a href="#" class="button small expanded hollow">Buy</a>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <h4>Top Products</h4>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <h4>Top Products</h4>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <h4>Top Products</h4>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-object">
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            </div>
            <div class="media-object-section">
                <h5>Nunc Eu Ullamcorper Orci</h5>
                <p>Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="callout large secondary">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <h5>Vivamus Hendrerit Arcu Sed Erat Molestie</h5>
            <p>Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 large-offset-2 columns">
            <ul class="menu vertical">
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <ul class="menu vertical">
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

slick.js

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function(){
    alert("worked");
    $('.product-slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: $('.prev'),
        nextArrow: $('.next')
    });
});
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but, here's my two-cents... Disable Turbolinks, there are tons of known issues with it and it's seldom worth the trouble.

Comment: Cool - I've totally done that before , wanted to work it out this time because I like the snappiness! I will definitely just remove it if I can't figure it out today

Answer (score 1):

I had to include .off(), in my document ready, otherwise the event bindings were piling up.

This code is at the bottom of a partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).off().on('ready turbolinks:load',function(){MyGlobal.slickInit();});
</script>
```

This is when I am defining MyGlobal.slickInit();

```
// $(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function(){
// });

MyGlobal.slickInit = function(){
    alert("worked");
    $('.product-slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: $('.prev'),
        nextArrow: $('.next')
    });
}
```

And I moved:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

To the bottom of application.html.erb, see below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>MySite</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Candal' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
    <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css"/>


</head>
<body>
    <!-- <div class="appWrap"> -->

        <%= render 'refills/centered_navigation' %>
        <div class="wrapper-for-content-outside-of-footer">
            <!-- Uncomment this whole section for a sticky footer. The content of the page should be inside of this .wrapper-for-content-outside-of-footer -->
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <%= render '/refills/footer_2' %>


    <!-- </div> -->

</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the following script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

into your application.html.erb? I've had issues with adding script tags within partials.

Comment: I did try that actually - in what section would you suggest placing it? I put it underneath the <body> and also inside the <head> section

Comment: Can you add it just above the <body> closing tag and see if it works,

Comment: I ended up adding it just beneath the body tag, and it worked...See below